# Exception is sometimes being thrown when coppying messages from folder to another using javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail

When trying to copy a list of messages from one folder to another, sometime this exceptions appears.

```
 nested exception is :
 com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A5 BAD COPY failed. Invalid messageset.
 at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.copyMesages(IMAPFolder.java.1769)
 Caused by:
 com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A5 BAD COPY failed. Invalid messageset.
 at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:353)
 at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.simpleCommand(Protocol.java:373) ...
```

My Code :

```
 public void moveMessageToTrash(String sourceFolder, String destinationFolder,
                         MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws MessagingException
  {
   IMAPFolder source = null;
   IMAPFolder destination = null;
   if(store.isConnected())
    {
     source = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder(sourceFolder);
     destin= (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder(destinationFolder);
     source.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
     destin.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    }
   Message [] messages = new MimeMessage[1];
   messages[0] = mimeMessage;
   source.copyMessages(messages,destin);
   source.setFlags(messages,new Flags(Flags.Flag.DELETED),true);
   source.expunge():
  }
```

EDIT :

Before removing the

```
   source.expunge();
```

The thrown exception was :

```
   messageRemovedException.
```

And nothing is being said by the debugger more than what is already said  on the initialization of the javamail session :

```
When the copy fails, nothing is said by the debugger. Everything is shown is only at the initialization of the session :

   INFO : DEBUG : JavaMail version 1.5.1
   INFO : DEBUG : failed to load any providers, using defaults.
   INFO : DEBUG : Tables of loaded providers.
   INFO : DEBUG : Providers Listed By Class Name :     {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTRANSORT=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTRANSPORT,Oracle,1.5.1]....
   INFO : DEBUG : Providers Listed By Protocol :
   ....
   INFO : DEBUG : failed to load address map, using defaults.
```

what i want to say is that after i removed the source.expunge() from the code, no exception is being thrown anymore, but actually the failure is still exists, some messages are being copied to the target and set deleted in the source, and a litle number of them are copied to the target but set deleted there, not in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly some of the messages you're copying have been deleted and expunged, either by your application or by some other application accessing the same folder?  A detailed protocol trace might provide more information.

Comment: now after i removed the source.expunge() from the method code, the copy operation is working. But something is going wrong when trying to copy several successive times. randomly one or two copy trials are failing. It seams that the setFlag DELETED is faster than the copy method!? could that happen ?

Comment: That shouldn't happen.  If you turn on JavaMail session debugging, what does the protocol trace show when it fails?

Comment: I have explained the case in more details in the question, hope that help you understand my situation.

Comment: If you're not getting the protocol trace in the debug output, you're doing something wrong.  Perhaps you're using multiple Session objects and only enabled debug in one of them?  We really need to see the protocol trace to see what's going on.  What server are you using?

Comment: I created only one session object in the glassfish(4) admin console, but I injected it 2 times in 2 different beans. I enabled the debug mode in the glassfish and in the 2 beans i set session.setDebug(true) each time. I am using JAMES-3-Beta-4 as a mail server.

Comment: In GlassFish, the JavaMail debug output is converted to java.util.logging messages.  You need to change the logging level for the corresponding logger; I forget what the name of the logger is.  My guess is that the problem is in JAMES; you might want to try with (e.g.) Gmail to see if the same problem occurs.